# Configure Munin to monitor multiple instances on one node

Tags: monitoring, freebsd, munin

I need to configure Munin to monitor multiple instances of a server daemon that run on a single host.

I've tried creating a different named symlink for each instance, but unless I also pass an env var that's appended to each service name I get "Service collision" errors.

With the suffix appended, Munin works, but then I just get one very large set of graphs, but where I'd very much prefer to have them grouped by instance instead.  Later, I'd also like to aggregate those graphs.

How can I configure this so that I get `node.instance.service` type grouping instead of `node.service_instance`?

I'm using a third-party plugin (https://github.com/shuque/bind9stats) on FreeBSD with the Munin 2.0.33_1 pre-built package.

Comment: Stating the version you're using might help.

Comment: @gf_ Good idea!  It's 2.0.33_1, from the FreeBSD package repo.

Comment: It also depends on the plugin you are using, can you tell us which one is it ?